# How would I calculate the standard deviation of a sample given the sample size, mean, and sum of the data's squares?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, sample

For example, given: $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = 10$, $n=10$, and $mean = 10$, how would I go about calculating the standard deviation? The formula for standard deviation requires me knowing what $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-mean)^2$ is, but that information is not provided to me in this problem.

Comment: See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sample standard deviation is given by

$$\begin{align*}
s
&=\sqrt{\frac{\sum\left(x_i-\bar{x}\right)^2}{n-1}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\sum\left(x_i^2-2x_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2\right)}{n-1}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{n\bar{x}^2+\sum x_i^2-2\bar{x}\sum x_i}{n-1}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{n\bar{x}^2+\sum x_i^2-2n\bar{x}^2}{n-1}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\sum x_i^2-n\bar{x}^2}{n-1}}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

so having $\bar{x}, n,\text{ and}\sum x_i^2$ suffices for calculating the sample standard deviation.

Comment: For the population standard deviation, the formula would be the same, except with n at the denominator instead of (n - 1) right?

Comment: That is correct